# Use incomparables=NA in duplicated() to return FALSE for duplicate rows with NA's

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the argument incomparables=NA in duplicated() to return a FALSE value for duplicates that are NA's. It works when my data argument is a single vector but not when the argument is a data frame. First example is without incomparables=FALSE so returns TRUE for second NA, second example returns FALSE for second NA, third example using data.frame but still a single vector yields an error, fourth example is what I want
to do, look for duplicates across a data frame of multiple columns, still gives an error.

````
> duplicated(c(1, 2, 2, 3, NA, NA))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

> duplicated(c(1, 2, 2, 3, NA, NA), incomparables = NA)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

> duplicated(data.frame(c(1, 2, 2, 3, NA, NA)), incomparables = NA)
Error: argument 'incomparables != FALSE' is not used (yet)```

> duplicated(data.frame(c(1, 2, 2, 3, NA, NA), c(2, 3, 3, 5, NA, NA)), incomparables = NA)
Error: argument 'incomparables != FALSE' is not used (yet)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different methods for `duplicated`

```
> methods('duplicated')
 [1] duplicated.array           duplicated.data.frame      duplicated.data.table*     duplicated.default         duplicated.matrix         
 [6] duplicated.numeric_version duplicated.POSIXlt         duplicated.vctrs_sclr*     duplicated.vctrs_vctr*     duplicated
```

If we check the source code for `duplicated.data.frame`, it is clear that it won't take any values other than FALSE in `incomparables`

```
> duplicated.data.frame
function (x, incomparables = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, ...) 
{
    if (!isFALSE(incomparables)) 
        .NotYetUsed("incomparables != FALSE")
    if (length(x) != 1L) {
        if (any(i <- vapply(x, is.factor, NA))) 
...
```

or for `array`s

```
> duplicated.array
function (x, incomparables = FALSE, MARGIN = 1L, fromLast = FALSE, 
    ...) 
{
    if (!isFALSE(incomparables)) 
        .NotYetUsed("incomparables != FALSE")
...
```

whereas for `default` option it works

```
> duplicated.default
function (x, incomparables = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, nmax = NA, 
    ...) 
.Internal(duplicated(x, incomparables, fromLast, if (is.factor(x)) min(length(x), 
    nlevels(x) + 1L) else nmax))
```

---

If we want to return `NA` as FALSE, an option is to create a condition with `is.na`

```
d1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, NA, NA))
duplicated(d1)& !is.na(d1)
      v1
[1,] FALSE
[2,] FALSE
[3,]  TRUE
[4,] FALSE
[5,] FALSE
[6,] FALSE
```